# Finding the volume of a rectangular-based pyramid using calculus?

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

I have a maths test coming up, and I just can't seem to solve a question on finding volumes of solids (via integration). Here's the question:

Find the volume of a pyramid with height h and rectangular base with dimensions b and 2b.

As straightforward as it seems, I am very confused. I would really be grateful for some help. If possible, please help me understand the solution using a simple diagram.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. You can certainly pose questions here, though homework or upcoming test questions are strongly discouraged. You have to show your effort in solving them otherwise you will un-neccsarily get downvotes. Usually people will help you as long as you show some effort.

Comment: Thank you for the enlightenment. I can assure you that this is not a homework problem, but a revision problem for my test. Since I have only been working with circular cross-sections and solids, I am really stuck and do not know where to start with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 1: **Using Calculus**

Consider the pyramid having apex point at the origin & its axis coinciding with the x-axis then at a distance $x$ from the origin, consider an elementary cuboid having small thickness $dx$ & a rectangular cross-section of width $b_x=\frac{bx}{h}$ & length $lx=\frac{2bx}{h}$
Then the volume of elementary cuboid $$dV=\text{(area of rectangular cross section)}\times {(thickness)}$$ $$dV=b_xl_xdx=\frac{bx}{h}\cdot \frac{2bx}{h}\cdot dx=\frac{2b^2}{h^2}x^2dx$$
Hence, the total volume of the pyramid $$V=\int dV=\int \frac{2b^2}{h^2}x^2dx$$ Using the proper limits of variangle $x$, we get volume of complete pyramid as follows $$V=\int_{0}^{h}\frac{2b^2}{h^2}x^2dx$$ $$=\frac{2b^2}{h^2}\int_{0}^{h}x^2dx$$
$$=\frac{2b^2}{h^2}\left[\frac{x^3}{3}\right]_{0}^{h}$$  $$=\frac{2b^2}{3h^2}\left[h^3-0\right]$$  $$=\frac{2}{3}b^2h$$

Method 2: **Using Geometry**

Volume of the right pyramid with rectangular base $$=\frac{1}{3}(\text{area of rectangular base})\times(\text{vertical height})$$
$$=\frac{1}{3}(b\cdot2b)\times (h)$$ $$=\frac{2}{3}b^2h$$

Comment: Thanks for your response. The question actually asks to find the volume using calculus (integration). Any luck with that?

Comment: That's good, you may check out both the methods in the answer

Answer (score 1):

So at height $x$ above the ground the cross-section is a $y\times 2y$ rectangle, which is the base of a smaller pyramid, height $h-x$ (the top slice of the larger pyramid).

Using **similar triangles** we see that $y=\cfrac {h-x}hb$ and the volume of a slice of small thickness $\delta x$ is approximately $\cfrac {h-x}hb\times \cfrac {h-x}h2b\times \delta x$.

Can I suggest you draw a diagram yourself - for example of a plane slice of the pyramid through the vertex and parallel to the side of length $2b$, which should give you a triangular section of height $h$ and base $2b$. It doesn't in fact matter if the vertex lies symmetrically above the base - if it does the triangle will be isosceles, but do another sketch too where it isn't and see that the calculation comes out the same. If you work out the diagram for this one yourself, I'm sure you will be able to work out others,

You need to "add" these slices together using the integral $$\int_{x=0}^h \frac {2b^2}{h^2}\cdot(h-x)^2dx$$

Comment: Would be easier (simpler expressions) if you count $x$ from the pyramid's apex towards its base. The $x$ value is then direct scaling factor between a section and the base dimensions.

Comment: @CiaPan Yes, it would come out a little easier. I had in mind that initially, for someone approaching this uncertainly, the intuition is that height goes up - and to work with that first.